# How to download Corporate Actions using Bloomberg blpapi

Tags: java, bloomberg, blpapi

I want to download **Corporate Actions** from **Bloomberg** (specifically **Bankruptcy Filing**, **Default Corp Actions**, **Default Resolution**) automatically every month and save it somewhere. To do this, I am using **Java blpapi**.

What I actually want to retrieve is the information when you do the following in Bloomberg Terminal.

1. **CACT** <**GO**>
2. Action Types: **Bankruptcy Filing**, **Default Corp Actions**,
   **Default Resolution**
3. Asset Types: **All Securities**
4. Effective Date: **09/24/2016 - 10/24/2016** (For example)
5. Exchange: **Global**

However, I am lost as to how to get Corporate Actions from blpapi. I only know how to retrieve **market cap** data through **Historical Data Request** and **outstanding shares** through **Reference Data Request**. What Reference Data Service should I use to retrieve corporate Actions data?

Comment: You can use a `ReferenceDataRequest` using `DVD_HIST_ALL` as a field. Note that the result will have a more complicated structure thant when asking for outstanding shares.

Comment: Hi @assylias! Thanks for your help but I think I wasn't very clear with my question. What I really wanted is to get the data when you do `CACT <Go>` for All Securities in **Bloomberg terminal** specifically for _Bankruptcy Filing_, _Default Corp Actions_ and _Default Resolutions_. When I tried `DVD_HIST_ALL` for a single security, it did not list the info I just mentioned.

Comment: Also, I undertsand that in blpapi, we should always indicate the security whose data we like to retrieve. However, is there a way that I do not have to separately indicate the securities and just retrieve data from all securities like  the option you have when you do `CACT <GO>`

Comment: No, you need to provide a list of tickers. I don't know that screen - you should ask HELP HELP what field you can use to retrieve the data that's in there and they should be able to help you.

Comment: Hi @assylias! Thank you so much!

Comment: IIRC, `DVD_HIST_ALL` that was mentioned above has the most comprehensive list of corporate actions. But even that requires you to specify a list of securities and doesn't contain all the actions that are listed in CACS<GO>. As mentioned, consult with HELP HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with Bloomberg Help Desk thru HELP HELP in Bloomberg Terminal, their reply is the following.

> We don't have an option to programmatically request CACT data. I would recommend making a template, {LPHP CACT:0:1 1015663} that you can reference when you run the function. The Java API will only include the data available from our Desktop API. You cannot create screening data in the Desktop API for CACT to request.

It seems that CACT data cannot be downloaded thru the blpapi. However, I am quite lost at what they mean by,

> You cannot create screening data in the Desktop API for CACT to
>   request.

Also, as @assylias mentioned in the comment above if we have a specific list of tickers, we can play with FLDS  to check for the fields we want to request. However in my case, I do not have a specific list of tickers that I can use to query blpapi. Thus, I will just go back in exporting this data from BBG terminal itself to an excel file.